# Power BI - Getting a forecast date from a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "DaysLeft" measure that I created that contains the number of days (Decimal) left until a specific Plant area is completed. So for each value in my "PlantArea" column, there is a unique "DaysLeft" measure value.

I now want to get the forecast date for when each "PlantArea" will be complete. Thus, Today()+DaysLeft for that particular plant area.

I've tried:

```
DATEADD(TODAY(), +[DaysLeft], DAY)
```

but that gives me nothing :(

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD()` only works for column. For measure, you can simply try

```
Forecast Date = NOW() + [DaysLeft]
```

`NOW()` is better than `TODAY()` for this case as it returns the current datetime instead of just date.

Result:

[image: result]